# Saving VRT file crashes QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

When I load a .vrt file, the image comes in with a black and blue tint usually or is some other weird color.  If I zoom in at all QGIS crashes and creates a minidump in my program folder. Also, when I try to Save-As the .vrt file (as a .Tiff and .vrt) the program entirely crashes and doesn't respond.  These are multiband rasters.

My ultimate goal is to turn the .vrt into a .tiff file.

I have all the images I used to create the .vrt file in case there is another route to accomplish this.

Comment: can you give us some clue as to what is in the vrt file?

Comment: Have you tried using `Raster > Conversion > Translate (Convert format)`

Comment: @iant a lot of jp2 (image) files.  I figured it was because the vrt is large but I haven't had a problem in the past with large files.

Comment: @Joseph Yes, just did and it took forever to go through with the algorithm and left a new layer with nothing on it.

Comment: can you open a single jp2 file?

Comment: @iant yes I can open them all and use them individually.

Comment: probably is a memory issue, could you convert them to geotiff and then mosaic the tiffs?

Comment: @iant no because they are multiband.  Mosaic only allows for singleband

Comment: I meant mosaic in the generic pop them in a vrt and process sense